# Webview is not getting notifications in windows 8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8.1

We have an existing Windows store application which was developed by using WPF4.5. It has a sign-in mechanism which uses the webview(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView). It loads a url into the webview and passes the windows credentials to that url. The url checks the user credentials if passes it will notify the webview with security token. If not it will notify the webview with error code or message.

This is working perfectly in Windows 8 store. However it is not working in windows 8.1 store. The webview is not getting any notifications from Html page that was loaded into it.

How to find root cause for this issue and resolve this issue?

**Things that I have tried out:**
I have searched in google and get the following articles which talks about webview in windows8.1.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227713
http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/appbuilder/archive/2013/07/17/what-s-new-in-webview-in-windows-8-1.aspx

As per the articles specified I have added the application uris in the app manifest file. Still issue is not get resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you confirm that the URL you are loading in the WebView is an https:// website?
You said you declared the URL I am assuming you did this in the AppManifest Content URI section.

I work for Microsoft (MSFT)